# Form error upon submitting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular-material, mean-stack

I have a form in which there is one required field and one non required field. Upon successful submission of form sending data to the server, I clear the data in both the input field models. However by doing that, the required field turns RED and shows error `This field is required`. How can I keep the required field error free after submitting the form and clearing its data. I want it to show error only when the user tries to submit the form with EMPTY REQUIRED FIELD.

```
<form name="myForm">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="100">
        <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="40">
            <input required type="text" placeholder="Book Name"
                   ng-model="bookName"
            />

            <div ng-messages="$error">
                <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>

        <span flex="10"></span>

        <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="40">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Theme"
                   ng-model="theme"
                   enter-pressed=""/>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
</form>

<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" flex="none" type="submit"
           ng-click="onSubmitClicked()">Submit
</md-button>


    $scope.onSubmitClicked = function() {
        $scope.bookName = ""; // this causes the REQUIRED FIELD ERROR AFTER I SUBMIT THE FORM
        $scope.theme  = "";
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto Asiel's answer, you should do the following after clearing the models.

```
                 if(form){ //make sure a form is passed as parameter
                     form.$setPristine(); //this will reset the form to its original state
                     form.$setUntouched();
                 }
```

`form.$setUntouched` will set the form to its untouched state hence removing the error message.

Answer (score 0):

please do the following:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="onSubmitClicked(myForm)">

  <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" flex="none" type="submit">Submit</md-button>
</form>


$scope.onSubmitClicked = function(form) {
    if (form.$valid) {
          // do what you have to do, the form is validated
        return;
    }

    // dont do anythign the form will flag ans $invalid and $submitted and the error messages will show
    return;

};
```